# dropdown menu css issue with IE8

Tags: css

Folks,

My dropdown menu work well in Chrome, Firefox, IE9 but not IE8.
When I place my cursor on dropdown about halfway it closes the drop down.
I am using `modernizr` on my project.

Also how can auto adjust the dropdown?

http://jsfiddle.net/zH6qH/

I appreciate any help.

I had to put code in order to submit. ignore below.

```
nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Anyone? Any help would be appreciated. thank you.